# Visual Studio 2012 Blue Warning icon in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2012 containing projects of different types but web projects show a little blue warning icon in the Solution Explorer. There's no any warning messages in the List of Errors. Building process doesn't show any error. I have been trying to find any reference issue, any missing file or library but everything seems to be right.
What does the blue warning icon means?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a source control program?

Comment: I am using Subversion but Tortoise doesn't show any conflict. I open the project in other machine which uses Subversion too and it doesn't show those icons.

Comment: Have you tried running a subversion "clean up"?

Comment: I've been trying to fix the issue and I found out that it is something related with ASP.NET 4.5 installation in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my machine had .Net Framework 4.6 and VS2012 without latest updates. The problem was solved updating VS2012.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a solution of mine, but I am on latest VS2022 but similar symptom. Ended up that I did not have the .NET Standard for 2.1 installed by default since its out of LTS, so I had to add it via Tools -> Get Tools and Features... -> Individual Components

Answer (score 0):

I found this searching for the same problem, except my situation was with VS2015.

Based on @MacLeod commentary, I verified that I did have pending changes for this project since I had just upgraded it to a new version of the Azure SDK.

I stashed my changes (I'm using git) and, what do you know, the icon went away.

It seems that besides the regular "red checkmark" icon, that blue icon is also used to signify that you have pending changes on that file for your versioning system.

(Disclaimer: I have not been able to find any trustworthy source on what possible icons are and what do they mean, this is just anecdotical data based on what I tried and was able to see.)